# How to find all next siblings from a particular class using css selectors

Tags: python, selenium, css-selectors, siblings, nextsibling

I want to scrape this website [Hotel Association Data](http://www.hanyc.org/members/hotels/) and need help for the css selector. If you see the below image, I am trying to extract address from here using a css selector.

Data I want to scrape : `20 West 29th Street` and `New York, NY 10001`

[image]

**Using Next Sibling Method**

I know we can find next sibling using `+` sign, but the problem here is both the address text doesn't have any `attribute` associated with it. I don't want to use `xpath` here but a generic css selector to find all the siblings of `.hanyccompany` and then extract text from it.

Can anyone tell me how to find all the siblings of `class='hanyccompany`

```
<span class="hanyccompany"><a href="http://www.acehotel.com/" target="_blank">ACE HOTEL NEW YORK</a></span><br />
20 West 29th Street<br />
New York, NY 10001<br />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse and extract data easily using BeautifulSoup.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from mechanize import Browser

br = Browser()
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Firefox')]
response = br.open("http://www.hanyc.org/members/hotels/")

web_data = response.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(web_data, "html.parser")
tags = soup.find_all('span', attrs={"class": "hanyccompany"})

for tag in tags:
    print(tag.parent.text)
    print("------------------------------")
```

if you print text of span's parent, you'll get something like

```
ACE HOTEL NEW YORK
20 West 29th Street
New York, NY 10001
Jan Rozenveld, Managing Director
(212) 679-2222
(212) 679-1947
jan.rozenveld@acehotel.com

...
```

Comment: I want to extract `address` not the `class=hanyccompany` or I want to extract all the siblings of `class=hanyccompany`

Comment: See updated post. you can iterate over tags list and get parent tag.

Comment: Or `tag.parent.text` will just give you inner text without  all tags.

Comment: web_data is  not a url. you are responsible to read url and pull html contents with whatever method you want. web_data contains final html

Comment: Nope its not working. My `web_data` contains all the html content but I can't see any output.

Comment: your program seems to be correct but it is so weird that I can see any tags :/

Comment: check what you get when you read web page. I'm sure you are not getting what you expect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106874/discussion-between-saleem-and-python).